# JavaScript: any tips on improving this code on opening/closing menu?

Tags: javascript, menu

I've been lurking w3schools for some time and studying javaScript. I've struggled for a few days with a code of which the function is to open and then close the opened menu on click again. I couldn't do this with a single , but I've managed to it with two.

I've managed to do this with the following method:

```
<div id="menuClosed" style="background: blue; color: white; width: 500px; height: 50px; transition: 0.3s">

    <p id="menuString" style="margin: auto; text-align:center;">
        Click on the button to open the menu
    </p>
    <button id="menuButton" onclick="changeStyle('Closed')" style="margin-left:250px;">Open</button>
    <div>
        <p style="font-size: 30px; text-align:center;">Bonefish</p>
    </div>
    <button id="menuButton2" onclick="changeStyle('Open')" style = "margin-left:250px; display: none;">Close</button>

</div>
<script>
    function changeStyle(idMenu) {
        //compresses OPEN and CLOSE buttons ID into a var
        var menuButton = document.getElementById("menuButton");
        var menuBotton2 = document.getElementById("menuButton2");
        //Compresses menu DIV's ID into a var
        var menuConfig = document.getElementById("menu" + idMenu);
        //styles that will serve as factor for opening/closing the menu
        var style1 = "background: blue; color: white; width: 500px; height: 50px; transition: 0.3s";
        var style2 = "background: blue; color: white; width: 500px; height: 150px; transition: 0.3s";

        //opens Menu and changes ID to "menuOpen"
        if (idMenu === "Closed") {
            menuConfig.style = style2;
            menuConfig.id = "menuOpen";
            menuButton.style = "display: none; margin-left:250px;";
            menuButton2.style = "margin-left:250px; display: initial;"
        }
        //Closes menu and chages ID to "menuClosed"
        if (idMenu === "Open") {
            menuConfig.style = style1;
            menuConfig.id = "menuClosed";
            menuButton.style = "display: initial; margin-left:250px;";
            menuButton2.style = "margin-left:250px; display: none;";
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I actually wanted to do, is to be able to both open and close the menu with the same button, but I can't figure out how.

I believe it can be done through changing `<button id="menuButton" onclick="changeStyle('Closed')" style="margin-left:250px;">Open</button>` changeStyle('Closed') into changeStyle('Open') and making necessary adjustments, but, again, my tries on that have failed.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: you can toggle in one function easly there is planty of duplication of this at SO

Comment: I tried toggling the button onclick to ="changeStyle('Open')" through menuButton.setAttribute = ("onclick", "changeStyle('Open')"); , but it didn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with this code? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could use `jQuery` and some `css`, it you'll get what you want
**UPDATED WITH JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var divmenu=document.getElementById('menu');
function toggleMenu(btn){
    if(btn.className=='open'){
        btn.className='close';
        divmenu.className='close';
        btn.innerText='Open';
    }else{
        btn.className='open';
        divmenu.className='open';
        btn.innerText='Close';
    }
}
```

```css
div{
   padding:10px 0; 
   color: white; 
   transition: 0.3s;   
   background: blue;
}
div.open{   
  height: 150px; 
  
}
div.close{ 
  height: 20px;   
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="close">
    <p id="menuString" style="margin: auto; text-align:center;">
        Click on the button to open the menu
    </p>
    <p style="font-size: 30px; text-align:center;">Bonefish</p>
</div>
<p style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:5px 0;"><button type="button" class="close" onclick="toggleMenu(this);">Open</button></p>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand jQuery. I know what's it for, but I haven't  yet grasped the syntax. Could you explain it in JavaScript? Thank you for your time, though.

Comment: converted to javascript

Comment: thank you, really! now it all works as I wanted it to

Comment: Glad it helped you!! Happy Coding